# Is there aluminum wiring in my vent fan?

Tags: electrical, exhaust-fan, aluminum-wiring

I just purchased and installed a new Panasonic FV-10NLF1 inline exhaust fan.  My house has copper wiring, but the wires on the fan appear to be aluminum (they are silver in color).  I didn't think anything was made with aluminum wire anymore.

What special considerations do I need to take when connecting the copper house wiring to the fan wires?

Comment: I've come across steel wires as well.  Usually when the wires are thin, and subject to physical forces.

Comment: I would make sure your insurance covers this situation. Some insurance policies will not cover homes with aluminum wiring. 
The easiest solution is just finding out for a fact if it is aluminum wiring, and then returning it and getting something compatible.

Comment: You can't buy new household electrical devices which use aluminum wire. It is either steel or tinned copper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes with stranded wire, they will tin the ends with solder.  I would guess this is the case here since you're right that aluminum is not usually used. I think the only reason they do this is to keep the ends from fraying and keep it neat.

You can check for sure by stripping new ends.

I have never seen stranded aluminum, or anything less than 12awg used (most house wire is 14awg copper, which is a bit smaller). You can see in this picture the aluminum is slightly bigger:

[image]

I would also be very surprised to see aluminum wire since it requires special wire nuts (co/alr rated) and an anti-oxidant paste (eg, Noalox) to connect.

If it's just tinned copper, you can twist and wire nut to a regular standed wire, just treat it like a normal copper wire.

Comment: +1, also aluminum wires can be stranded, but each component will be at least 2,5mm<sup>2</sup>, so that only happens for wires with cross-section of more than 25mm<sup>2</sup> - not something that one will find in a bathroom fan.